# Mean reverting SDE applications

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, applications, stochastic-differential-equations

I know some of famous mean reverting stochastic differential equations .
such as below.Please help me to make this list better .If you know one or more of this kind (of equation) please add below .I am thankful for your help in advanced .

\begin{array}{c||c}
Model- name & equation \\
\hline
Vasicek- model (1977) & d{{r}_{t}}=(\theta -\alpha {{r}_{t}})dt+\sigma d{{W}_{t}} & \\
\hline
Cox–Ingersoll–Ross- model (1985) & d{{r}_{t}}=(\theta -\alpha {{r}_{t}})dt+\sqrt{{{r}_{t}}}\sigma d{{W}_{t}} & \\
\hline
Hull–White- model (1990) & d{{r}_{t}}=({{\theta }_{t}}-\alpha {{r}_{t}})dt+{{\sigma }_{t}}d{{W}_{t}} &\\
\hline
Fokker–Planck -equation & \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial t}} = \theta \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}[(x - \mu )f] + \frac{{{\sigma ^2}}}{2}\frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {x^2}}}\\
\hline
  stochastic -version-of- falling -object & dv = (g - \frac{k}{m}v)dt - \frac{k}{m}\alpha {dW_t}\\
\hline 
Schwartz- 1997- commodity -models & \frac{dS}{S} = \alpha(\mu-lnS)\,dt +\sigma\, dW \\
\hline 
Schwartz -1997- commodity- models & \begin{aligned}
\frac{dS}{S} &= (r-y)\,dt +\sigma\, dW \\
dy &= \alpha(\theta-y)\,dt+\epsilon \,dZ \\
dWdZ&=\rho\,dt 
\end{aligned}\\
\hline 
Heston- model & \begin{aligned}
dS_t &= \mu S_t\,dt + \sqrt{\nu_t} S_t\,dW^S_t \\
d\nu_t &= \kappa(\theta - \nu_t)\,dt + \xi \sqrt{\nu_t}\,dW^{\nu}_t
\end{aligned} \\
\hline 
\end{array}

Comment: Most commodity models are mean reverting. See Schwartz 1997.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schwartz 1997 commodity models:

1 factor
$$
\frac{dS}{S} = \alpha(\mu-lnS)\,dt +\sigma\, dW
$$

2 factors
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dS}{S} &= (r-y)\,dt +\sigma\, dW \\
dy &= \alpha(\theta-y)\,dt+\epsilon \,dZ \\
dWdZ&=\rho\,dt 
\end{aligned}
$$

Heston model
$$
\begin{aligned}
dS_t &= \mu S_t\,dt + \sqrt{\nu_t} S_t\,dW^S_t \\
d\nu_t &= \kappa(\theta - \nu_t)\,dt + \xi \sqrt{\nu_t}\,dW^{\nu}_t
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You could list the Cheyette model which is particular case of the HJM model,

$$r_t=\phi_t+x_t$$ $$dx_t=(y_t-\kappa(t)x_t)dt+\eta(t)dW(t)$$ $$dy_t=(\eta(t)^2-2\kappa(t)y_t)dt $$

where $\phi_t$ and $\kappa$ are deterministic.

You would note that if $\eta$ is deterministic, the model is Gaussian. Better, you can choose $\eta$ in a way that the extended Vasicek model is a particular case of the Cheyette model.